# Как сделать работающую базу данных?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Как сделать чтобы бд работала, сделал как [тут](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/12.1.php), но вызывается исключение:

```
Вызвано исключение: "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException" в System.Data.dll
```

Добавил в Web.config

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;
    AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\FormsAuth.mdf;
    Initial Catalog=FormsAuth;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

И сам класс:

```
public class UserContext : DbContext
{
    public UserContext() :
        base("DefaultConnection")
    { }

    public DbSet<UserForAuthorization> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Какая строчка кода бросает исключение?

Comment: По текущей приведённой информации ничего толком сказать нельзя. Вот расскажите по порядку. Вы создали пустое приложение asp.net mvc + identity (app-in storage) -- оно у вас СРАЗУ после создания работало, запускалось? Обычно, с нуля созданное приложение должно стартовать без проблем - и для мне эта точка очень важна: если вы скажете, что "да, работала", то мы будем разбирать файл за файлом, строчка за строчкой что вы меняли пока вдруг не перестало работать. От пустого работающего приложения меняется два файла: один (ApplicationUser) вы показали, второй  (ApplicationDbContext) нет. Покажите оба.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, Когда идет обращение к бд. Такое чувство, что либо путь не указан к нему (Хотя кодом выше указывается путь), либо бд создается не только тут

Comment: @АндрейNOP user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == model.Name && u.Password == model.Password);

Comment: @chilo5432 Для отладки программы придумали очень хорошие средства. Поставьте брейкпоинт на проблемной строке и по шагам смотрите что происходит с программой, а что еще важнее - вам покажут полный текст исключения.

Comment: Я бы проверил строку соединения. Больше не чему ломаться)

Answer (score 0):

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Clients2015-20171203033252.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Clients2015-20171203033252;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>


    public class Client
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name1 { get; set; }
        public string Name2 { get; set; }
        public string Name3 { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }

    public class ClientsDb : DbContext
    {
        public ClientsDb() : base("DefaultConnection") { }
        public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Всё равно: Вызвано исключение: "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException" в System.Data.dll